# Buscar una fila mediante una subcadena

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo una tabla Juego con la variable `nombre`, que obviamente es una cadena de caracteres.

Pues bien, he creado un formulario para buscar una fila mediante una subcadena:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Introduzca el nombre del juego que busca</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="busca_nombre" novalidate>
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="nombre" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Nombre del juego que busca</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="nombre" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('nombre') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="nombre" value="{{ old('nombre') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if($errors->has('nombre'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('nombre') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ auth()->user()->id }}"/>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Buscar Juego
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Y esto lo paso a la siguiente función:

```
public function encuentroNombre(NombreRequest $request){

    public function encuentroNombre(NombreRequest $request){
        $juegos=Juego::where(stripos('nombre',$request->nombre),'>',0)->orderBy('numero')->get();
        if(count($juegos))
            return view('saludos',compact('juegos'));
        else
            return back()->with('message',['danger','No se ha encontrado ningun juego cuyo nombre contenga la palabra escrita.']);
    }
```

Pues bien, me sale este mensaje de error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where
>   clause' (SQL: select * from `juegos` where `` > 0 order by `numero`
>   asc)

¿Como indico que quiero que compruebe si una subcadena esta en la variable `nombre` de la tabla Juego?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo usando LIKE

Concatenando "%":

```
$juegos = Juego::where('nombre', 'like', '%'.$request->nombre.'%')->orderBy('numero')->get();
```

O usando (Complex curly syntax):

```
$juegos = Juego::where('nombre', 'like', '%{$request->nombre}%')->orderBy('numero')->get();
```

Comment: Esta bien, aunque me he encontrado un problema: ¡Esto no distingue la N de  la Ñ!

Comment: Eso es por la codificación de tu tabla, puedes probar con latin1_spanish_ci  y debería funcionarte.

Comment: En phpMyAdmin lo tengo como latin1_swedish_ci. ¿Como lo modifico?

Comment: Vale, ya se como cambiarlo.

Comment: Y ya se distingue la N de la Ñ.